# How to use library jar after import to existing project

Tags: android

I create gallery app , then i want to add zoom effect to images in my gallery  by adding an external library called :  ImageVIewZoom.jar
 From this link:
 https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom
I only add the jar file not all ImageViewZoom project to my project .

I add the library following this way :

1- my libs -> right click -> Import -> File System -> ImageViewZoom.jar

2- myProject -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> ImageViewZoom.jar.

Now jar file already in my project how can i utilize or use jar class inside my gallery class so i finally when run my app , my images will have zoom effect .

Am new to android and first time to use external library inside my project ,

**Edit:**
 Does i need to add some code inside my gallery class or inside the imports , if so how it will be .

this is my gallery class , actually its not my code but i founded here in stackoverflow and use it to form infinite gallery .

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class DayGallery extends Activity {
TextView tv;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the layout to use
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InfiniteGallery galleryOne = (InfiniteGallery) findViewById(R.id.galleryOne);
    galleryOne.setAdapter(initializeImages()); 
    galleryOne.setSelection(galleryOne.getCount()/2);  
             }           


private InfiniteGalleryAdapter initializeImages() {
    InfiniteGalleryAdapter galleryAdapter = null;

    String day = getIntent().getStringExtra("dayname");


    if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("london")){
        int[] tempimages = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher };  
        String[] name = { " 1"," 2", " 3"};  

        galleryAdapter=new InfiniteGalleryAdapter(this, tempimages, name); }

    else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("paris")){
        int[] tempimages = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher };  
        String[] name = { "4","5", "6"};  

        galleryAdapter=new InfiniteGalleryAdapter(this, tempimages, name); }

    else if(day.equalsIgnoreCase("rom")){
        int[] tempimages = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher };  
        String[] name = { "7","8", "9"};  

        galleryAdapter=new InfiniteGalleryAdapter(this, tempimages, name); }


                 }

    }

    return galleryAdapter; 
           }
          }


 class InfiniteGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
private Context mContext;
private int[] images;   
private String[] name;
public InfiniteGalleryAdapter(Context c, int[] imageIds,String[] names) { 
    this.mContext = c; 
    images = imageIds;
    name=names;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); }

public int getCount() { 
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
               } 

public Object getItem(int position) { 
    return position; 
           } 

public long getItemId(int position) { 
    return position; 
           } 

private LayoutInflater inflater=null; 


public class ViewHolder{ 
    public TextView text; 
    public ImageView image; 
                   } 


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ImageView i = getImageView(); 

    int itemPos = (position % images.length); 

    try { i.setImageResource(images[itemPos]); ((BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable()).setAntiAlias(true); 
              } 

    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) { Log.e("InfiniteGalleryAdapter", "Out of memory creating imageview. Using empty view.", e); 
                          } 

    View vi=convertView; 
    ViewHolder holder; 
    if(convertView==null){ 
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_items, null); 
        holder=new ViewHolder(); holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); 
        vi.setTag(holder); } 

    else holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag(); 
    holder.text.setText(name[itemPos]); 

    final int stub_id=images[itemPos]; 
    holder.image.setImageResource(stub_id); 

    return vi; 
              } 

private ImageView getImageView() { 

    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext); 

    return i; 
         } 
            }

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 class InfiniteGallery extends Gallery {

public InfiniteGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
               }

public InfiniteGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(); 
              }

public InfiniteGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(); 
                  }

private void init(){
    // These are just to make it look pretty
    setSpacing(50);
    setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
             }
            }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated .thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct way to add .jar libraries. You can use it the same way you did in regular java(assuming).

```
ABCD a = new ABCD();
a.method();
```

In your case, your library has a sample code. [See here.](https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom/blob/master/ImageViewTouchTest/src/it/sephiroth/android/library/imagezoom/test/ImageViewTestActivity.java)

Regards,

Comment: Does i need to add some code inside my gallery class or inside the imports , if so how it will be . thanks